# how to move files to different folders , based on matching filename and foldername in ssis

Tags: file, loops, for-loop, ssis, each

I have four files xxxxxxCd999, xxxxCf999, xxxxC999  , xxxxD999 ... I need to move these files to their respective folders based on file name , for example file xxxxxCd999 should be moved to folder Cd999 , file xxxxCf999 should be moved to folder Cf999 ,file xxxC999 should ne moved to folder C999  so on ... 
How do I achieve this in ssis ?

I have used a for each loop container, assigned some variables for   sourcepath, destinationpath , and a file system task to use these variables ,  but im lost now n have no idea how to proceed , 
Kindly help me

Comment: Are the above folders already created ?

Comment: Yeah the destination folders are already present

Answer (score 3):

Try this :-

The `Foreach Loop` will enumerate the source  folder and the path will be stored in a variable. In the `script task` write a code to get the folder Name using regular expression .The script task value will be stored in another variable which will be used in `File System Task`

The package design will be

[image]

- Create 3 variable

  ```
   Name         DataType   Expression
   FolderName    string
   DestLoc       string     "D:\\"+ @[User::FolderName]   
   LoopFiles     string
  ```

In the above expression for `DestLoc` variable ,change it as per your location

- ForEach Loop configuration
  [image]

[image]

Change the source folder location as per the need

- Script task -Add the 2 variable as below 
  [image]
- You need to extract the folder name from the variable `LoopFiles`

Example

`LoopFiles` variable will have `D:\ForLoop\SampleFolder1.txt` at runtime

So in order to extract folder name from the above variable use regular expression

Open `Edit Script` and write the following code

```
List<string> filePatterns = null;

public void Main()
 {
     filePatterns = new List<string>();
     filePatterns.Add("Folder1");
     filePatterns.Add("Folder2");
     string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Dts.Variables["User::LoopFiles"].Value.ToString());
     Match match = Regex.Match(fileName, string.Join("|", filePatterns.ToArray()));
     Dts.Variables["User::FolderName"].Value = match.Value;
     Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
  }
```

In the above code ,you are extracting the folder name and storing it in the variable `FolderName`.If you have `multiple folders` ,then just add the `folder names` to the `filePatterns` collection variable.

- File System Task Configuration

[image]

Comment: Hi I am having a similar requirement. When I followed your process, I am getting an error saying: "[File System Task] Error: An error occurred with the following error message: "The given path's format is not supported.".
"

Comment: if you select "name and extension" in the for each loop configurator, you don't need to extract the name from the variable later, it will just store the filename