# Move files with SSIS to different directories dynamically based on excel file names

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, msbi, script-task

How to move multiple excel files to different folders based on file name in ssis? means based on the file name it will move to respective folder.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: i added a foreach loop container with script task and i am stuck in script task only. @Nick.McDermaid

Comment: A script task is not neccesary but if you like C# it might be your best option. Alternatively I suggest you read this http://www.sqlyoga.com/2014/09/sql-server-ssis-rename-and-move-files.html and come back with _specific_ questions

Comment: without script task can we do this with any other task? please suggest me.

Comment: Seems like you didn't read my link

Comment: It is moving to only one archive folder but i want based on file name it will move to respective folder.

Comment: It seems you need to alter the expression to do that for you. You haven't actually explained the rule that you want to use. Please edit your question and explain what you've tried, explain the rule you want to use, and show some examples.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

In this you can see that you have to create a foreach loop, a script task a and a file system task to move the files to destination folder.

[how to move files to different folders , based on matching filename and foldername in ssis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15287943/how-to-move-files-to-different-folders-based-on-matching-filename-and-folderna)

Comment: this is not working, running successfully but files are not moving.

Answer (score 0):

### Using Foreach loop container

1. You have to add a for-each loop container to loop over files in a specific directory.
2. Choose the follow expression as a filename:

   `*takeme*`
3. Map the filename to a variable
4. Add a dataflow task inside the for each loop to transfer files
5. use the filename variable as a source

*you can follow the detailed article at:*

- http://www.sqlis.com/sqlis/post/Looping-over-files-with-the-Foreach-Loop.aspx

if you want to add multiple filter follow my answer at:

- [How to add multiple file extensions to the Files: input field in the Foreach loop container SSIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43195171/how-to-add-multiple-file-extensions-to-the-files-input-field-in-the-foreach-loo/43198065#43198065)

### Using a script task

or you can achieve this using a script task with a similar code: (i used VB.Net)

```
Public Sub Main()

    For Each strFile As String In IO.Directory.GetFiles("C:\New Folder\", "*takeme*", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)

        Dim filename As String = IO.Path.GetFileName(strFile)

        IO.File.Copy(strFile, "D:\New Folder\" & filename)

    Next

    Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success
End Sub
```